# similarity word with Trigram

Tags: python, django, postgresql, full-text-search

how i make a function for word similarity in search result.
For example if i write in my search form "ugo" or "hugo". i try this :
("contenue" is my column for txt files in db postgresql)
views.py

```py
class SearchResultsList(ListView):
    ...
    ...
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        vector_column = SearchVector("contenue", weight="A", config='french')
        search_query = SearchQuery(query)
        search_headline = SearchHeadline("contenue", search_query)
        result1 = Q(contenue__search=query)
        result2 = Q(SearchVector("contenue"))
        return Actes.objects.filter(result1).annotate(headline=search_headline)
        .annotate(similarity=TrigramSimilarity('contenue', query) ,)
        .filter(similarity__gte=0.6).order_by('-similarity')
```

when i don't add trigram i have a result but not work if i write "ugo" instead of "hugo" or "higo" instead of "hugo".
Thank and sorry for my bad english

Comment: ugo has only 2 same trigrams from 5 that are in word hugo which would result similarity score less then 0.6 => 2/5 = 0.4

Comment: ok, thank you :) , i try this i think my function don't working, i have result only if i change `(similarity__gte=0)`